# Sound editing - car misfueled, what sort of sound?

Tags: car, sound-editing, broken, engine

Hello! My first post here, but Ive been a long-time background user.

I have a scene in a film I'm working on, and a car is mis-fueled (petrol put into a diesel car)

I dont drive (yet) and I havn't experienced this before. i would like to make my soundtrack as realistic as possible and Im wondering if any of you know what it sounds like?

Hope you can help!

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b5xhPAundL4&feature=related

At first there is little difference, but the longer you drive the car the greater the effect, the above video might help.

Comment: Thanks @iainmcgregor for the help! Im my film the car dies much quicker than it does in this real-life test, but Im certain now that all i need is a stalling diesel car engine... Now where to find that.....

Answer (score 0):

@twosdotsound I'm no expert but it may sound more believable to the audience if the 'Breaking down' sound was a car in a higher gear than it should be for the travelling speed. It creates a "juddery" sound before eventually stalling.

Comment: @chriswinter Thanks man, I was sifting through some sound effect and decided to just get out and record my dad stall the car a few times. You were correct too, the higher gear did the trick! Your more the expert than you think!

Answer (score 0):

I think Chris is on the right track.

Answer (score -1):

i would transform some diarrhea sounds, be great and very realistic to;)